# Gradle exclude dependency from a task

Tags: gradle, vaadin7, vaadin4spring

I have a task "vaadinCompileWidgetset" which won't work if javax-validation-1.1 is on classpath (it depends on javax-validation-1.0). The problem is, my build depends on 1.1 so I can't exclude the artifact from the build.

Is it possible to exclude the dependency or force 1.0 on the vaadinCompileWidgetset task only?

Comment: is it this task? https://github.com/johndevs/gradle-vaadin-plugin/blob/d3f31598e1b9ab0fe434785dea2842e54990a02b/src/main/groovy/fi/jasoft/plugin/tasks/CompileWidgetsetTask.groovy

Comment: @AdamSkywalker correct, and I should also not, this solution: https://github.com/johndevs/gradle-vaadin-plugin/issues/162 didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you try to set correct jars to classpath through this project variable ? https://github.com/johndevs/gradle-vaadin-plugin/blob/d3f31598e1b9ab0fe434785dea2842e54990a02b/src/main/groovy/fi/jasoft/plugin/tasks/CompileWidgetsetTask.groovy#L119